# Spring boot database listener with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, listener, mysql-event, database-events

Is there any way to implement a **database listener** with Java using **MySQL** as database?

Searching on Google I see that there are many solutions for Oracle with `DatabaseChangeListener` and `DbChangeNotification`, but nothing about *MySQL*...

I need an event that it's triggered when a value is greater than another value in the database... any solutions?

I don't want implement a pool request that check the database manually with a specific interval time :(